# partialview modal popup showing as flexslider image gallery in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, flexslider

I'm trying to bind values to partialview modal popup to show data as flexslider image gallery.

I have _Layout page, inside that layout I included _partialview layout, using this partial view **_layout** I'm showing modal popup.

Entered that partialview in main **_layout** page as follows

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="image_slider">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_ImageGalleryPartialView.cshtml", new ProjectName.ViewModels.ImageViewModel())
</div>
```

this is the ajax call use to call the function on controller method

```
        // Ajax Call

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ImageGallery',
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            data: { some_parameter_values },
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
        })
          .success(function (result) {
              $('#image_slider').html(result);                            
              $("#image_slider").modal("show");
          })
         .error(function (xhr, status) {
             alert(status);
         })
```

This is the controller method I'm using to feed this model popup , If this is working properly, I should be get list of images with their case IDs

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult ImageGallery(some_parameter_values)
{
    try
    {    
        ImageViewModel listofimage = new ImageViewModel();
        ...
    }           

        return PartialView("_ImageGalleryPartialView", listofimage);   

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }

}
```

**ImageViewModel.cs**

```
public class ImageViewModel
{
    public ImageViewModel() 
    {
       ImageValues = new List<Images>();         
    }

    public IList<Images> ImageValues { get; set; }
}

public class Images
{
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public string ImageValue { get; set; }
}
```

I have a partilview modal popup as follows

**_ImageGalleryPartialView.cshtml**

```
@model ProjectName.ViewModels.ImageViewModel

<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header"> </div>

        <div class="modal-body" style="width: 530px;">

            <div id="slider_view" style="display: block;">
                <div class="flexslider">
                    <ul class="slides">
                    @for (int item = 0; item < Model.ImageValues.Count; item++)
                     {
                     <li data-thumb="~/Upload_Images/@Model.ImageValues[item].ImageValue">
                     <img src="~/Upload_Images/@Model.ImageValues[item].ImageValue" data-imagedata="@Model.CCDImageValues[item].ImageName" />
                     <p class="flex-caption">@Model.ImageValues[item].ImageName</p>
                    </li>
                     }
                   </ul> 
        </div>
      </div>
            <div id="grid_view" style="display: none;">
        <div class="row">
                 @for (int griditem = 0; griditem < Model.ImageValues.Count; griditem += 3)
                 {
                  <div class="col-lg-12 pad-6">
                     @for (int loopvalue = 0; ((loopvalue < 3) & (loopvalue < Model.ImageValues.Count)); loopvalue++, griditem++)
                     {
                        <div class="col-lg-4 pad-0">
                           <img src="~/Upload_Images/@Model.ImageValues[griditem].ImageValue" width="170px" />
                           <span class="span-mark">@Model.ImageValues[griditem].ImageName</span>
                       </div>
                    }
                 </div>
                }

        </div>
    </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this output not bind properly, how to ajax bind values to this model in ajax call success event

```
.success(function (result) {
                  $('#image_slider').html(result);                            
                  $("#image_slider").modal("show");
              })
```

when I insert something like in

```
<div class="modal-body" style="width: 530px;">
@for (int item = 0; item < Model.ImageValues.Count; item++) 
{ 
  @Model.ImageValues[item].ImageName
}
</div>
```

but outside `<div id="grid_view" style="display: none;"></div>` and `<div id="slider_view" style="display: block;"></div>`  I can see values binding

Comment: What is your `AbnormalDataStationIdLeadCarNo()` method? You need to show the relevant code

Comment: @StephenMuecke I missed something, now oky please see the updated question

Comment: You would not even be hitting that method (check you browser console for errors!) - `url: '@Url.Action("ImageGallery")',`, remove the `contentType` option and remove the `data` option (that method does not even accept any parameters)

Comment: @StephenMuecke that method call when I click button on view page, when this is clicking I'm sending some parameters , sorry I removed them, to keep question simplicity

Comment: @StephenMuecke when I insert something like `@for (int item = 0; item < Model.ImageValues.Count; item++)
                     { @Model.ImageValues[item].ImageName }` in `<div class="modal-body" style="width: 530px;">`    but outside  `<div id="grid_view" style="display: none;">`  and   `<div id="slider_view" style="display: block;">` I can see values bind, but I'm trying to bind this properly as flxslider gallery, I think issue in success event how I'm bind success event result to this modal-dialog

Comment: Which plugin are you using and how are you initializing it?

Comment: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/ ,`how are you initializing it?` I'm not understand  you're saying this is not an issue, when I'm binding values to modal dialog in success event in ajax call .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128986/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kez).